# How can I set extent when .prj files are identical?

Tags: projection, extent

I have two .shp files whose .prj files are identical and whose extents are different. I'd like to set them to the same extent so they line up on the map.

In ArcGis  I have tried:

- Exporting both to a new coordinate system-defined feature dataset
- Removing the .prj file and then re defining the projection of each file
- "project"ing both to the same Coordinate system.
- Setting the data frame Coordinate System, then reintroducing the shapefiles in hopes that they'll project "on the fly"

In QGIS I have tried:

- Setting project CRS
- Setting layer to project and project to layer
- Saving the shapefiles in specific CRS.

It seems odd to me that this is an issue in the first place: why can't Arc or Q detect this asynchronicity and give the user the option to choose one over the other?

What am I missing here?

Should I look into creating a spatial reference for one of the files, that matches the other?

Any clues/ suggestions/ clarifications?

I know this is a popular issue, and I figure there must be some simple explanation for the above, but I'm not finding it anywhere despite spending hours puzzling over the situation. Perhaps I just don't have the right vocabulary to ask the question. Any help appreciated.

some information about the files:

Extents for shp1:

top: 672344.187336 ft 
bottom: 629117.938976 ft 
right:7660465.885171 ft 
left: 7627858.786745 ft

Extents for shp2:

top: 5984.800593 ft 
bottom: 4784.800593 ft 
right: 4616.411043 ft 
left: 3776.411043 ft

Layer Properties-Source for both shp1 and shp2:

Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Oregon_North_FIPS_3601_Feet_Intl
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  8202099.73753281
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -120.50000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    44.33333333
Standard_Parallel_2:    46.00000000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 43.66666667
Linear Unit:    Foot

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983_HARN
Datum:  D_North_American_1983_HARN
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree

.prj data for both shp1 and shp2:

PROJCS["NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Oregon_North_FIPS_3601_Feet_Intl",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_HARN",DATUM["D_North_American_1983_HARN",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",8202099.737532808],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-120.5],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",44.33333333333334],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",46.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",43.66666666666666],UNIT["Foot",0.3048]]

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have the same problem, in the course of answering this question (r/gis/reddit proved the most useful) I learned:

1. There are local coordinate systems which might not show up on Arc or Q. In this case, the data was derived from a CAD file, a DWG that I converted for a project.
2. One can change the data frame projected coordinate system within Arc trying to find a fit. In this case there was none, no matter how long or hard I tried
3. Some Coordinate systems are simply so local they aren't useful, or as a redditor put it, "garbage", so don't waste your time trying to make them fit.

4.The Spatial Adjust tool can be used to effectively georeference a dataset with an unknown coordinate system to one which is known. So in my case, I took the .shp and then used the spatial adjust toolset to "rubbersheet" it to some clearly defined data. Easy. Took a few minutes. Made it fit, defined projection, called it good.